# How do i add slugs to a URL, but still redirecting to the same page

Tags: php, url-rewriting, javascript, urls

So this might be a little hard to explain, but i will try my best :).

I have a Webshop running woocommerce, and i have multiple categories, with multiple subcategories.
One of the pages is setup to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGKal.jpg), with a little javascript magic, and help from

```
window.history.pushState
```

When you press a category the URL will change:

```
From www.webshop.com/slug/
To   www.webshop.com/slug/category1
```

Pressing a category will bring up all the subcategories (see illustration again), then pressing one of the subcategories will change the URL:

```
From www.webshop.com/slug/category1  
To   www.webshop.com/slug/category1/subcategory1
```

This is all fine and great, and works exactly as its supposed to - but if you try to link to *www.webshop.com/slug/category1/subcategory1*, you will get redirected to a 404 - because it obviously doesn't exist.

What I'm interested in, is that i want it to links to the www.webshop.com/slug/ with the categories in the URL open.

I have as i see it 2 problems, 1 big & 1 minor:

1. I need it to open the /slug/ site but with appended with /category1/subcategory1 - this is the harder of the problems i presume.
2. I need it to open the categories when.

But how am i supposed to fix these problems? To be honest I have no clue, since i don't know what to search for - so cant gather any information about it.

I was hoping somebody could point me in the right direction, or similar - so i could get this worked out:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there's a reason the subcategory URL has to be `www.webshop.com/slug/category1/subcategory1`, I would modify this to use a hash instead - i.e. `www.webshop.com/slug/category1#subcategory1`

This way you won't break WordPress's permalink structure and you can still easily use the hash with JavaScript so render the correct content on the page.

Comment: Can you use multiple #? so i have #category1#subcategory1?

Comment: You can only have one hash but you could chain them with a different delimiter (which you might have to urlencode)